# Program added to path but cmd not recognizing/finding it (ruby version manager for windows)

Tags: ruby, cmd, pik

I've installed pik in a windows machine so I can manage my ruby versions I also added the path to the PATH variable, but pik is not being recognized, I also created an alias but that just results in an error when it's used but the program runs fine when I run it directly ("C:\ruby_bin\pik").

What is going on?

p.s. ruby is installed in "C:\ruby", just so you know.

Comment: So how exactly does your `PATH` now look? (just type `path`) Did you run `pik_install`?

Comment: I did do `pik_install` and the last part of my `path` looks like ` C:\ruby_bin; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the windows installer and that worked, don't know why it worked over the ruby gem version but whatever, so lesson for the future, just use the windows installer.